# Count of documents changes if a sorted column is selected

Tags: lotus-notes

I have an All view in one database that is behaving very strangely. If I select all documents in the view when it is first opened, I get 2213 (correct number). Each column in the view is sorted (both). If I sort on one of the columns, the total count in the view drops to 133? Strangely this does not happen on every sorted column. The view is indexed (I deleted the index and re-indexed it and it made no difference). Has anyone ever seen this behavior before and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Are any of the columns categorized?

Comment: Nope. Checked that first. All are set to None/Standard with the Click on Column Header set to Both.

Comment: Did you try an updall -T <view> -R? How about a non-replica copy (or a replica for that matter) to see if you get the same behavior in a different physical file?  And one more question: Does this database have an obscenely high number of replica stubs? It's been a while, but I've seen some weirdness in views in databases that have a smallish number of documents, but they are short-lived documents - created and deleted frequently and stubs are not purged, so that internal structures in the NSF file appear to reach limits and things behave badly.

Comment: Could that be due to "Show Multiple Values as Separate Entities" being enabled somewhere?

Comment: Checked that too

Comment: It turned out that changing a column formula and then changing it back worked. I guess it rebuilt the internal index. Changing one column resulted in all columns now returning the correct number of documents.